# Check the existence of multiple parameters in dust.js

Tags: dust.js

I've just started using dust.js. And I've come across a problem.
I need to specify a condition (json parameters existence) in template. Depending on it some inner html should be rendered or not. So according to the description I should use smth like this:

```
{?param_name}
...
{:else}
{/param_name}
```

But I need to check a complex condition, so I go for logic helper - {@if..}. And it turns out that I'd like to use path in condition. So.. The result looks:

```
{@if cond="{myObject.property1} || {myObject.property2} || {myObject.property3}"}
..
{/if}
```

And the problem is when some property is undefined the evaluation stops on smth like:

```
(true) || () || ()
```

producing a syntax error.

Could you please tell what approach should I use to check the existence of multiple params?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested way is

```
{@if cond="('{myObject.property1}'.length} && '{myObject.property1}') || ...
```

But I find this pretty horrible.

I would write a specific helper to do this.  Look at the code for @if - https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/blob/master/lib/dust-helpers.js#L196

Comment: Thanks Tom! I'll start with the horrible one (=

Comment: @godspeed Godspeed! ;)

Comment: The link you provided points to the master branch. That is a problem because the line number is outdated. Actually, dust no longer even supports ```@if```

Comment: @DavidMoritz, "if" is deprecated.. is there a replacement for this?  I need to check a && condition.  "select" appears to only have "none" or "any" I would think they should have an "all" but I can't seem to find it any where.

Comment: @RayLoveless, I'd say the solution would be to create a computed value, put your logic in there, and check against that.